# Copy folder with files to "Android/data" of other application (Android 11)

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to copy folder named **"test"** with file **"test.txt"** to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files` folder, but I always get an error like:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/com.android.chrome/files/test/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

I gave all permissions, tried workarounds, but nothing works.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```kotlin
val folder = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir("test"))
val path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/com.android.chrome/files"
folder.copyRecursively(File(path), true)
```

I know that in Android 11 and above "you can't" access another data folder, but if you take any modern file explorer from google play, then it can easily open, modify, delete any files in `Android/data` and its subdirectories.

I will be grateful for any help. If I missed a similar question, please let me know in a comment.

Comment: "if you take any modern file explorer from google play, then it can easily open, modify, delete any files in Android/data and its subdirectories" -- many of those will request `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Your app may be rejected from the Play Store or other app distribution channels, though, unless you can provide a good justification for having that permission.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the help! I don't need to load my app on Play Store. That is, `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission will help me?

Comment: It will help in terms of being able to work more broadly with external storage.